# Adding a servlet to run in Intershop 7.4 application server context

Tags: servlets, guice, intershop

I'm trying to include a 3rd party servlet to run in our IS7 application server's context. How would I go about adding the servlet and mapping to the web.xml?

In the knowledge base I have only found information regarding Enfinity Suite 6. None of the steps provided seem to work.

*EDIT:*

I found a proposed solution for IS7 using Guice and binding the servlet via a specific Servlet module like

```
package com.intershop.test;

import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;

public class MyServletModule extends ServletModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets()
    {
        bind(MyServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
        serve("/my/*").with(MyServlet.class);
    }
}
```

I have added my ServletModule to the objectgraph.properties file but my servlet still isn't called when I try accessing it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this works in ICM 7.7 but I believe it has been around since 7.4.

You may use the [Guice Servlet Extension](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Servlets).

1.Declare dependency to the Guice Servlet in your cartridge `build.gradle`. *Example*:

```
dependencies 
{
    ...
    compile group: 'com.intershop.platform', name: 'servletengine'
    compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet'
    ...
}
```

2.Define a servlet module in the cartridge `objectgraph.properties`. *Example*:

```
global.modules = com.example.modules.DemoServletModule
```

3.Implement your servlet. *Example*:

```
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.getWriter().append("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

4.Create the module implementation. **Gotcha:** The name should start with `/servlet/` as pointed in the comments. *Example*:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;

public class DemoServletModule extends ServletModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets()
    {
        bind(DemoServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);

        serve("/servlet/DEMO/*").with(DemoServlet.class);
    }
}
```

4.Build, restart, try. *Example*:

```
GET /servlet/DEMO/hey HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:10054
....
```

Reposnse:

```
Hello, world!
```

**UPDATE:**

If you would like that your servlet is visible through the webadapter you have to allow it.

1.Open `IS_SHARE\system\config\cluster\webadapter.properties`

2.Navigate to this section:

```
## The list of servlets, which can be accessed through the generic
## .servlet mapping. The WebAdapter forwards only requests of the form
## /servlet/<group><servlet.allow.x>...
```

3.Add entry for your servlet. *Example*:

```
servlet.allow.4=/DEMO
```

4.Access the servlet on a similar URL:

```
https://example.com/INTERSHOP/servlet/WFS/DEMO/hey
```

Comment: Hi Lachezar! Thanks for your help. It kind of put me into the right direction. I didn't need to declare the 'servletengine' and 'guice-servlet' dependencies. It worked without.
My mistake was rather declaring the access path in the servlet module with just "/DEMO/*" - putting "/servlet" in front of my servlet path fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is was really doing my head in.