# How to create Elastic APM spans for each pipeline call

Tags: intershop, elastic-apm

I  would like a recommendation on how to instrument each pipeline call using Elastic APM API on Intershop 7.10.

I want to to create a separate span as described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/public-api.html#api-span-start-span
(Using try catch block with parent.startSpan())

For now I have tried looking into ICM knowledge base for topics regarding ELK stack (found none) and looked in Component Framework section on how to inject some code around PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline or put another pipeline processor implementation through component framewowrk but couldn't find nothing, it seems for now that pipeline processor implementation are not hooked through Component Framework.

Answer (score 1):

General answer is, you should **not** bother replacing `PipelineProcessor` with your own implementation. Even for such a seemingly *small* task of feeding your own monitoring solution.

I (may) have a better solution for you. Haven't tested it though. Have a look at the detailed answer to this intershop question: [Adding a servlet to run in Intershop 7.4 application server context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035113/adding-a-servlet-to-run-in-intershop-7-4-application-server-context)

You don't want to add a new servlet but you want to bind a new `javax.servlet.Filter` implementation that hooks into the Application Server request chain. You can do that the same way as described, but invoke method `filter("/servlet/Beehive/*")` instead of `serve("/servlet/DEMO/*")`